How should I seal around these roof lights on this EPDM rubber roof?
I have an out building roof with roof lights that are leaking. The roof lights are glass on top of a built up surround with EPDM rubber roofing. The windows were not installed long ago, and were put into replace worse windows that leaked due to poor design (the company that did the work have tried to stop the leaks 5 times now and I am inclined to do what looks like a final bit of sealing myself rather than call them out again as the windows themselves look OK).
The water appears to be getting in due to incomplete / broken sealant under the window. I'm also concerned that a layer of the rubber may be leaking water where it is not glued down properly. What actions should I take?
If adding more sealant is the solution, what type of sealant should I use for gluing down EPDM rubber and / or sealing around the join between the window glass and rubber covered surround?
The attached photos show the rooflight as a whole, a close up of sealant between the glass and rubber covered surround, a EPDM rubber layer lifting slightly.




The epdm layer should be brought over the surround to avoid the leaks.

The EPDM layer comes up the edges of the wooden surround and over the top. The glass window then sits on top of this. Is this what you mean?
